# Filtering options data

Tags: options, implied-volatility, data, delta, theta

I am looking to conduct some analytics with regards to options implied volatility. My advisor mentioned about filtering options with time to maturity of less than 7 calendar days. Is there a particular for that?

Like maybe the options price or implied volatility spikes too much etc.

Happy to provide any additional details.

Comment: He wants you to filter off options with less than a week before expiry or focus only on those?

Comment: She* wants me to filter off options with less than a week before expiry.

Comment: Let me answer with another question... what's the vega of an option with less than 7 days to maturity?

Comment: @KT8 I’m intrigued.

Comment: Vega vanishes (not just around ATM) as $\tau \to 0$. This can potentially make the fitting of implied volatilities unstable

Comment: Ah thank you! I think I understand now, she probably wants me to remove those options data due to their lack of price stability and probably illiquidity. The implied volatilities might come up to weird values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible they want you to remove short dated options as the vol of implied volatility increases. In real price terms this isn't visible as much, that's because $\frac{dC}{d\sigma_i}$ decreases with $\sqrt{T}$ for close to ATM strikes.

You see this frequently in 1DTE options in crypto where trades go through at ridiculously high vol of vol but is actually just a function of the bid/offer spread skewing the IV.